# cin.get() is not getting out of loop

Tags: c++

I am using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char c ;
    c = cin.get() ;
    do {
        cout.put(c) ;

        c = cin.get() ;
    } while ( !cin.eof()) ;

    cout << "coming out!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Problem with the above code is, its not getting out of loop, which means its not printing "coming out". Anybody can help why it is so? I am testing this program on mac and linux.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard in never hits EOF, unless you press Ctrl+Z.

Therefore, `cin.eof()` is always false.

To fix it, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to send an End-Of-File character.
Alternatively, you could change the condition.  (eg, `while(c != '\n')`)

Comment: Though your answer while(c != '\n') works on terminal, but it stuck when i try to give input using file. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 5):

It does print "coming out" provided that it gets the end-of-file. It will go out of the loop if you redirect a file to it with

```
./program < file
```

or send the end-of-file yourself, by hitting ctrl+d (linux) or ctrl+z (dos)

Comment: Well if i use the following command to run it, it came out of it. ./main < input.txt >output.txt . But is there anyway if i can give input on command prompt? Thanks

Comment: If i hit ctrl+d (linux), its not printing "coming out"

Comment: As others have mentioned (for dos/windows) and I have just added, you can always tell the program when you end transmitting information to it

Comment: You have to make sure you hit it on an empty line (just after enter)

Answer (score 2):

Works perfectly well here :) If you run this in a terminal you have to send EOF to this terminal. On *nix this would be Control + D. I cannot say anything about Windows unfortunately.

Edit: As others have pointed out: Ctrl + Z would be the Windows way of sending EOF.

Answer (score 1):

You need to press CTRL-Z to simulate EOF (End-of-File) and to exit the loop.

If you don't press CTRL-Z, the loop will continue to run forever.

Comment: Or CTRL-D on non-Microsoft platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a guess about intent, because there's nothing wrong with that code but it's probably not what you intended, and will also suggest a while loop uhhh.. while I'm at it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool is_terminator(char ch)
{
    return ch != '\n' && ch != '\r';
}

int main ()
{
    char ch;
    while (cin.get(ch) && !is_terminator(ch) )
        cout.put(ch);

    cout << "coming out!" << endl;
}
```